# Applying a verb to two subjects

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct?

If Insurance company or Law Firm have changed their opinion then please let us know.

or

If Insurance Company or Law Firm has changed its opinion then please let us know.

Comment: You have modified two different things (*have* / *has* and *their* / *its*) at the same time. That makes it impossible to answer in a reasonably coherent fashion—and also doesn't indicate your *specific* area of concern.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

> If the Insurance company **or** Law Firm **has** changed **its** opinion, then
> please let us know.

[The use of "or" implies one or the other and NOT both.](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/moduleSVAGR.htm)

This answer is different like this:

> If the Insurance company **and** Law Firm **have** changed **their** opinions, then
> please let us know.

Another thing you might note is this same concept throws native speakers and many might do this wrong and use the plural form of the verb.  (i.e. *have* instead of *has* with **or**)

Also, very few native speakers will correctly use "its" as the possessive in the sentence using "or."  Most would probably use "their."

Thanks to @Acccumulation, another good reference for this would be:
https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/subject_verb_agreement.html

@Acccumulation put this in the comments, so I wanted to reference him/her.

Thanks @Acccumulation!

Comment: This would be better with references, such as https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/subject_verb_agreement.html  And it is a bit prescriptive.

Comment: Thanks @Acccumulation I found a reference and added yours.